# Remove words when match with first 3 or 4 characters

Tags: python, regex

```
words_to_remove  = ['sstlgh8j', 'abchjk9j']
```

I need to remove the words in the sentance which starts with sst or abc

I have a sentence in this way:

```
1) error in node occurred in sstlgh8j at 10pm afterabchjk9j after 12pm
2) error in node occurredsstlgh8j at 10pm after abchjk9j after 12pm
```

I need to remove those words from the above two sentences. I tried with regex sub module but not
working

```
re.sub('(?:\s)sst[, ]*', '', my_string)
```

It is removing the word when there is a space only

```
Desired output:
    1) error in node occurred in at 10pm after 12pm
    2) error in node occurred at 10pm after 12pm
```

Comment: What is `'(?:\s)cj[, ]*'` supposed to match? How did you use `words_to_remove`? Why did you define `words_to_remove` at all?

Comment: Updated the regex module. the 'words_to_remove' list has the words that has to removed when present in the sentence.

Comment: Ok, try `re.sub(r'\s*(?:abc|sst)\w*', '', my_string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
my_string = re.sub(r'\s*(?:abc|sst)\w*', '', my_string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CyygLJ/1). *Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(?:abc|sst)` - either `abc` or `sst`
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars. Replace with `[^\W\d_]*` to match any Unicode letters or `[a-zA-Z]*` to only match ASCII letters.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Np2t9u):

```py
import re
texts = ['error in node occurred in sstlgh8j at 10pm afterabchjk9j after 12pm',
'error in node occurredsstlgh8j at 10pm after abchjk9j after 12pm']
rx = re.compile(r'\s*(?:abc|sst)\w*')
for mystring in texts:
    print(rx.sub('', mystring))

# => error in node occurred in at 10pm after after 12pm
#    error in node occurred at 10pm after after 12pm
```

Comment: How to make it generic instead of just checking with abc or sst? I have a list of words that has to be removed from the text. The list of words might change periodically.

Comment: @merklexy That will look like `terms = ['abc','sst']` and then `rx = re.compile(fr'\s*(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, terms))})\w*')`. See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/2A6fmA).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way if you prefer not to use regex:

```
words_to_remove  = ['sstlgh8j', 'abchjk9j']

a = "1) error in node occurred in sstlgh8j at 10pm afterabchjk9j after 12pm"
b = "2) error in node occurredsstlgh8j at 10pm after abchjk9j after 12pm"

def clean(a,words_to_remove):
    a = a.split(" ")
    for word in words_to_remove:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if(word in a[i]):
                a[i]=""
    a = [x for x in a if x]
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]):
            a[i]=""
    return(" ".join([x for x in a if x]))

print(clean(a,words_to_remove))
print(clean(b,words_to_remove))
```

Output:

```
1) error in node occurred in at 10pm after 12pm
2) error in node at 10pm after 12pm
```

Comment: If the sentence only has 2 words and one of the words contains words_to_remove, it will remove the sentence completely. How to fix it?